# block gives error when trying to execute it from the model class

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my tableViewController I have this kind of code (here is simplified):

```
-(void)saveOnDatabase{

//here I set up NSManagedObjectContext and everything


[[[array objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"tableLabels"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

    if (obj==solvent) {
        [pepe setValue: [self numberFromText:delta :2] forKey:obj];
    }else {
        [pepe setValue: nil forKey:obj];
    }

}];


}
```

It works ok and it does what I expected. However to keep code clean, I want to execute this code from my model, a subclass of NSObject where I do all the calculations and everything that has nothing to do with UI. The thing is that when I try to implement it on the model Class it gives me errors such as: `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int((^))(void)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(__strong id, NSUInteger, BOOL*)'`

the block is contained withina method like:

```
-(void)saveCustomToDatabase:id  withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context withImpurity:(NSString*)impurity  withDelta:(NSString *)delta ... // the rest
```

I don't really know what's the deal here and why it doesn't even compile on the other class, taken into account that I pass all the necessary parameters...

The complete methos is exactly this one:

```
-(void)saveCustomToDatabase:id  withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context withImpurity:(NSString*)impurity  withDelta:(NSString *)delta withAssigment:(NSString*)assigment withEntity:(NSString*)entity withSolvent:(NSString*)solvent {


            NSManagedObject *pepe = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity inManagedObjectContext:context];

            if (assigment.length>1) [pepe setValue:assigment forKey:@"definition"];

            [pepe setValue:impurity forKey:@"impurity"];


[[[[self pickerArray] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"tableLabels"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

    if (obj==solvent) {
        [pepe setValue: [self numberFromText:delta :2] forKey:obj];
    }else {
        [pepe setValue: nil forKey:obj];
    }

}];

NSError *error;

if (![context save:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


}
```

Comment: Show us the actual code that produces the error.

Comment: S&%&*)&   I've just spoted the proble, which was on the declaration of the method. The 'id' on this declaration should be gone.